# uninstall "not installed" apps

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have Android 5 on my HTC One M8. Only have a guest user and my own user. still there are apps - partly restored by titanium backup - listed in my app manager. They're marked as "not installed". They stay there even when I uninstall them. any idea? br Tom

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall them with adb from your computer:

```
adb uninstall <package_name>
```

Make sure you have USB debugging enabled:-)